# Define right button of NavBar in component, not in Scene (react-native-router-flux)

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using `react-native-router-flux` for navigation in my app.

I want to define right button of `NavBar` in component, not in `Scene`, how should I do this?

Here is the code of the `Scene`:

```
 <Scene
          navBar={PlatformNavbar}
          leftElement={  <Text style={{color: Colors.white, marginLeft: 25, fontWeight:'500' }}>Go Back</Text>  }
          key='nodScreen'
          component={NodScreen}
          hideNavBar={false}
        />
```

I'm using my custom `navBar`, I have functions for rendering right and left element: `leftElement`, `rightElement`.

In order to render right element in the component, I was using this code, however, it didn't render anything.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Actions.refresh({rightElement: this.renderRightElement
  }) }

  renderRightElement = () => {
    return ( <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {} }>
    <Image style={{height: 24, width: 24, marginRight: 16}} source={{uri: 'score_progress_empty'}} resizeMode='contain'/>
 </TouchableOpacity>)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `right` instead of `rightElement`

```
componentDidMount() {
  Actions.refresh({
    right  : this.renderRightElement,
  })
}
```

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2518) on RNRF page for more details